# Add badge alert in right bar button item in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have placed a simple button in right bar button position. This button is showing my cart. Now i'm trying to place a badge on that button which will show my cart items count. I'm trying it by using FontAwesome pods. I have placed a right bar button item but when i run that it replace the right bar button of count with the cart button. I want it to come on the cart button and show the count.How can i get that? 
This is what i'm trying to place a badge on right bat button

```
let rightButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:20,height:20))
  rightButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 15)
  rightButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .circle), for: .normal)

  let rightButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)

  rightButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20)
  rightButton.titleLabel?.text = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .github)

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem
```

This is how my cart button shows before
[image]

This it looks after right bar button code
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create File named 'UIBarButtonItem+Badge.swift'
and add the following code

```
import UIKit

extension CAShapeLayer {
func drawRoundedRect(rect: CGRect, andColor color: UIColor, filled: Bool) {
    fillColor = filled ? color.cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor
    strokeColor = color.cgColor
    path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 7).cgPath
}
}

private var handle: UInt8 = 0;

extension UIBarButtonItem {
private var badgeLayer: CAShapeLayer? {
    if let b: AnyObject = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &handle) as AnyObject? {
        return b as? CAShapeLayer
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func setBadge(text: String?, withOffsetFromTopRight offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color:UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
{
    badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    if (text == nil || text == "") {
        return
    }

    addBadge(text: text!, withOffset: offset, andColor: color, andFilled: filled)
}

private func addBadge(text: String, withOffset offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color: UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
{
    guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }

    var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

     if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular) } 
     let badgeSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])

    // Initialize Badge
    let badge = CAShapeLayer()

    let height = badgeSize.height;
    var width = badgeSize.width + 2 /* padding */

    //make sure we have at least a circle
    if (width < height) {
        width = height
    }

    //x position is offset from right-hand side
    let x = view.frame.width - width + offset.x

    let badgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: offset.y), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))

    badge.drawRoundedRect(rect: badgeFrame, andColor: color, filled: filled)
    view.layer.addSublayer(badge)

    // Initialiaze Badge's label
    let label = CATextLayer()
    label.string = text
    label.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    label.font = font
    label.fontSize = font.pointSize

    label.frame = badgeFrame
    label.foregroundColor = filled ? UIColor.white.cgColor : color.cgColor
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    label.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    badge.addSublayer(label)

    // Save Badge as UIBarButtonItem property
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &handle, badge, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}

private func removeBadge() {
    badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
}
```

And now simple add the badge in UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
let rightBarButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

rightBarButton?.addBadge(number: 4)
```

Comment: Edited. check now

Comment: Its showing error in this line
  if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
      font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
    }
    
    let badgeSize = text.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])

Comment: what is UIFontWeightregular and NSFontAttributeName? @Taimoor Suleman

Comment: Replce these 3-4 line with this - if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
         font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
      }
      
      let badgeSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])

Comment: This works fine but in some cases the Badge starts on left side of button, where I can fix this?

Comment: By Setting the X Position of Badge

Answer (score 1):

Here it is simple solution

```
let filterBtn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
filterBtn.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .filter, style: .solid,
                                                   textColor: UIColor.white,
                                                   size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)), for: .normal)
filterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

let lblBadge = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
self.lblBadge.backgroundColor = COLOR_GREEN
self.lblBadge.clipsToBounds = true
self.lblBadge.layer.cornerRadius = 7
self.lblBadge.textColor = UIColor.white
self.lblBadge.font = FontLatoRegular(s: 10)
self.lblBadge.textAlignment = .center

filterBtn.addSubview(self.lblBadge)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: filterBtn)]
```