# how to put badge on UIBarButtonItem in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I want put badge on UIBarButtonItem. for that I use the following reference

[Add badge alert in right bar button item in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329779/add-badge-alert-in-right-bar-button-item-in-swift)

in this I create the 'UIBarButtonItem+Badge.swift' file and put that code in it. In my viewcontroller I take the outlet of the UIBarButtonItem. And call the function but it didn't work for me. my viewcontroller file is this

My UIBarButtonItem+Badge.swift file is

```
extension CAShapeLayer {
func drawRoundedRect(rect: CGRect, andColor color: UIColor, filled: Bool) {
    fillColor = filled ? color.cgColor : UIColor.white.cgColor
    strokeColor = color.cgColor
    path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 7).cgPath
   }
  }

   private var handle: UInt8 = 0;

   extension UIBarButtonItem {
private var badgeLayer: CAShapeLayer? {
    if let b: AnyObject = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &handle) as AnyObject? {
        return b as? CAShapeLayer
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func setBadge(text: String?, withOffsetFromTopRight offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color:UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
{
    badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    if (text == nil || text == "") {
        return
    }

    addBadge(text: text!, withOffset: offset, andColor: color, andFilled: filled)
}

 func addBadge(text: String, withOffset offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero, andColor color: UIColor = UIColor.red, andFilled filled: Bool = true, andFontSize fontSize: CGFloat = 11)
{
    guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }

    var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular) }
    let badgeSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])

    // Initialize Badge
    let badge = CAShapeLayer()

    let height = badgeSize.height;
    var width = badgeSize.width + 2 /* padding */

    //make sure we have at least a circle
    if (width < height) {
        width = height
    }

    //x position is offset from right-hand side
    let x = view.frame.width - width + offset.x

    let badgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: offset.y), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))

    badge.drawRoundedRect(rect: badgeFrame, andColor: color, filled: filled)
    view.layer.addSublayer(badge)

    // Initialiaze Badge's label
    let label = CATextLayer()
    label.string = text
    label.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center
    label.font = font
    label.fontSize = font.pointSize

    label.frame = badgeFrame
    label.foregroundColor = filled ? UIColor.white.cgColor : color.cgColor
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    label.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    badge.addSublayer(label)

    // Save Badge as UIBarButtonItem property
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &handle, badge, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}

private func removeBadge() {
    badgeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
   }
  }
```

my viewcontroller file is this

```
import UIKit

@IBOutlet weak var notificationLabel: UIBarButtonItem!
```

in view didload function

```
notificationLabel.addBadge(text: "4")
```

Comment: I'm currently also facing this problem. Setting the badge asynchrounously worked for me, but is just a work-around: `DispatchQueue.main.async { notificationLabel.addBadge(text: "4") }`

Comment: its working but some time show some time not.

Comment: any proper solution ? @ Andreas Oetjen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is a simple solution for putting the badge on a navigation bar

```
let filterBtn = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
filterBtn.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .filter, style: .solid,
                                                   textColor: UIColor.white,
                                                   size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)), for: .normal)
filterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

let lblBadge = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
self.lblBadge.backgroundColor = COLOR_GREEN
self.lblBadge.clipsToBounds = true
self.lblBadge.layer.cornerRadius = 7
self.lblBadge.textColor = UIColor.white
self.lblBadge.font = FontLatoRegular(s: 10)
self.lblBadge.textAlignment = .center

filterBtn.addSubview(self.lblBadge)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: filterBtn)]
```

**In your case**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [notificationLabel.init(customView: filterBtn)]
```

Comment: but where to put in my navigation bar? I take outlet of UIBarButtonItem. where to put that here?

Comment: try this
`notificationLabel.init(customeView: filterBtn); 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [notificationLabel].`

Comment: @sohan123 one upvote would be appreciated...Thank you

Answer (score 18):

Here is a swift 4 solution of @VishalPethani with small convenient changes.

Add this UIBarButtonItem to you code:

```
class BadgedButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    public func setBadge(with value: Int) {
        self.badgeValue = value
    }

    private var badgeValue: Int? {
        didSet {
            if let value = badgeValue,
                value > 0 {
                lblBadge.isHidden = false
                lblBadge.text = "\(value)"
            } else {
                lblBadge.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }

    var tapAction: (() -> Void)?

    private let filterBtn = UIButton()
    private let lblBadge = UILabel()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setup()
    }

    init(with image: UIImage?) {
        super.init()
        setup(image: image)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup(image: UIImage? = nil) {

        self.filterBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        self.filterBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        self.filterBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        self.filterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.lblBadge.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15)
        self.lblBadge.backgroundColor = .red
        self.lblBadge.clipsToBounds = true
        self.lblBadge.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        self.lblBadge.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.lblBadge.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        self.lblBadge.textAlignment = .center
        self.lblBadge.isHidden = true
        self.lblBadge.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        self.lblBadge.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.filterBtn.addSubview(lblBadge)
        self.customView = filterBtn
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        if let action = tapAction {
            action()
        }
    }

}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let btn = BadgedButtonItem(with: UIImage(named: "your_image"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn

        btn.tapAction = {
            self.btn.setBadge(with: 1)
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a repository for that with some customisation 
https://github.com/Syngmaster/BadgedBarButtonItem

Comment: When you set the badge value the bar button item is no longer showing @syngmaster

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIBarButtonItem {
        
    convenience init(icon: UIImage, badge: String, _ badgeBackgroundColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9156965613, green: 0.380413115, blue: 0.2803866267, alpha: 1), target: Any? = self, action: Selector? = nil) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
        imageView.image = icon

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -8, y: -5, width: 18, height: 18))
        label.text = badge
        label.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 18 / 2
        label.textColor = .white

        let buttonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
        buttonView.addSubview(imageView)
        buttonView.addSubview(label)
        buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: target, action: action))
        self.init(customView: buttonView)
    }
    
}
```

> Use:

```
item = UIBarButtonItem(icon: UIImage(), badge: "\(Test)", target: self, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
  func setBadge(with value: Int) {
    guard let lblBadge = customView?.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel else { return }
    if value > 0 {
      lblBadge.isHidden = false
      lblBadge.text = "\(value)"
    } else {
      lblBadge.isHidden = true
    }
  }
  
  func setup(image: UIImage? = nil) {
    customView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let lblBadge = UILabel()
    lblBadge.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15)
    lblBadge.backgroundColor = .red
    lblBadge.tag = 100
    lblBadge.clipsToBounds = true
    lblBadge.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    lblBadge.textColor = UIColor.white
    lblBadge.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    lblBadge.textAlignment = .center
    lblBadge.isHidden = true
    lblBadge.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    lblBadge.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    customView?.addSubview(lblBadge)
  }
}
```

Steps:

1. Drag an drop an UIButton in navigation/toolbar or add it programmatically using customView initializer.
2. Call setup method in view didload:

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   ```
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    itemsButton.setup(image: UIImage(named: "image_name"))
   ```

   }
3. Connect an @IBOutlet/or programmatically and call setBadge method everywhere you need:

   badgeButton.setBadge(with: 10)